# Writing a simple array program in python

Tags: python

I have a simple problem and the statement goes like this:

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
I want to create the numbers as above:

The code that I am trying to write is as follows:

```
num(1)=1
num(2)=2
for i in range(3,10):
    num(i)=num(i-1)+num(i-2)
    print num(i)
```

The algorithm that I designed is as follows:

```
x(i)=x(i-1)+x(i-2)
```

I will start from `x(3)` with `x(1)` and `x(2)` unknown. Can anyone help me with in array syntax error ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
num = range(1, 10)
num[0] = 1
num[1] = 2
for i in range(2,9):
    num[i]=num[i-1]+num[i-2]
    print num[i]
```

You need to use `[]` instead of `()`

Answer (score 2):

[Python uses `[]`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) to address indexes in <del>array</del> list, so just use `num[i]` instead of `num(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for lists is to use square brackets ("[" and "]" like "num[3]"), not parenthesis. Then you have to remember that in programming indexes in lists start with 0, not 1. Then when you're done with that you have to create a list in the first place: num = [].